# Lost the appcenter in Loki

Tags: release-loki, apt, appcenter

I lost the app center in loki after doing `sudo apt-get autoremove`
i cant seem to locate the file  or the app.
A correct name of the package might help me install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out how apt-get autoremove had anything to do with the disappearance of appcenter.

The man-page for apt-get claims the autoremove command " is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed."

Researching in the web one can see some users that reported problems by using apt-get autoremove though.

If appcenter has been uninstalled anyhow, you should type in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install appcenter`

Answer (score 0):

Its just appcenter I verified with dpkg -L appcenter and looked in synaptics where it also shows up as appcenter.